# List comprehension to find all numbers between 1 and 1000 which contains 7

Tags: python, list, list-comprehension

I am trying to fina all numbers b/1 1 and 1000 that contain 7.

Tried:

```
lst=[y for y in range(1,1000) if 7 in y]
print (lst)
```

Got below error:

```
TypeError: argument of type 'int' is not iterable
```

Tried:

```
lst=[y for y in range(1,1000)]
newlst=[]
str1=list(map(lambda x:str(x),lst))

for i in str1:
    if any('7') in i:
        newlst.append(i)
print (newlst)
```

This gives

```
if any('3') in i:
TypeError: 'in <string>' requires string as left operand, not bool

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Any idea to accomplish this with list comprehension?

Comment: to be clear, `7` as a digit like `17` rather than as a factor like `49`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`7 in y` is invalid, because `in` works for containers and `y` is not an iterable.

`any(<string>)` is *also* invalid (semantically, not syntactically) because the result of the expression is a boolean (as you've surmised). `any` performs short circuiting on a sequence, evaluating the truth values of every element in the container/iterable it receives. Since all strings (besides the empty string) are `True`, `any(<non empty string>)` evaluates to `True`, so the use of `any` to begin with does not make much sense. In fact, had you just done `if '7' in i`, that would've worked.

To answer your original question, you can convert `y` to a string and check whether the character `'7'` is present.

```
[y for y in range(1, 1000) if '7' in str(y)]
```

For your information, you can also use a `lambda` and `filter` out values of interest.

```
list(filter(lambda x: '7' in str(x), range(1, 1000)))
```

Although, I don't recommend this because `filter` (especially with a `lambda`) in general is *slower* than its list comprehension equivalent.

It's possible to be even more functional and `map` `str` on the range:

```
list(filter(lambda x: '7' in x, map(str, range(1, 1000))))
```

The iterator version with `lambda`, either of the last two options but without applying `list`, is only worthwhile when you are iterating over a large number of items.

Comment: Why would you use `in` for equal test?

Comment: @MegaIng See the comment under your answer, that's not what OP wants.

Comment: @MegaIng _"I am trying to fina all numbers b/1 1 and 1000 **that contain 7**"_. I agree that the sentence is a bit hard to parse (likely because the OP is not a native English speaker), but if you look carefully he/she wants to test if `7` is _in_ a certain number, not if seven _is_ a certain number.

Comment: as an alternative to filtering, you could build the set, `{'7' + i + j  for i in "0123456789" for j in "0123456789"} | {i + '7'+ j
   ...:  for i in "123456789" for j in "0123456789"} | {i + j + '7'  for i in "1
   ...: 23456789" for j in "0123456789"} | {'7' + i for i in "0123456789"} | {i 
   ...: + '7'  for i in "123456789"} | {'7'}`.  while it could be cleaned up and made a bit more efficient,  it's probably not as fast as @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ

Answer (score 0):

If you're concerned about performance, consider doing a *generator comprehension* instead which is many orders of magnitude faster than the *list comprehension*.

```
# adapting coldspeed's approach to generator comprehension
(y for y in range(1, 100000) if '7' in str(y))
```

---

```
In [86]: %timeit [y for y in range(1, 100000) if '7' in str(y)]
21.8 ms ± 883 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)

In [87]: %timeit (y for y in range(1, 100000) if '7' in str(y))
555 ns ± 3.72 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000000 loops each)
```